# Javascript framework can't really call methods internally

Tags: javascript, plugins, frameworks

I have been trying to mimic some of jQuery's syntax for a much smaller plugin. I have struggled with using methods of the $ object internally for a while now. Let me illustrate:

```
(function() {
    window.$ = function (element) {
        return new Plugin(element);
    };

    var Plugin = function (element) {
        this.element = element;
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {
        foreach: function(callback) {
            // Of course the "foreach" function will be bigger than this, this is just for testing.
            var values = [];
            for (i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {
                values[i] = callback.call(this, this.element[i], i);
            }

            return values;
        },
        someOtherFunctionThatUsesForeachInternally: function() {
            var arr = [];
            $([6, 32, 2]).foreach(function(item, key) {
                arr[key] = item + 7;
            });
            return arr;
        }
    };
})();

/* Desired result: 
[
    [13, 39, 9],
    [13, 39, 9],
    [13, 39, 9],
    [13, 39, 9]
]
*/

var arr = [1, 5, 7, 9];
var test = [];

$(arr).foreach(function(value, key) {
    test[key] = this.someOtherFunctionThatUsesForeachInternally();
});

console.log(test);
```

A new Plugin object is instantiated whenever the dollar sign is used in conjunction with an argument (such as an array, in the example this would be `var arr = [1, 5, 7, 9]`) and a method is immediatly called after that.

I wrote a small `foreach` to test with, but it appears to be impossible to call it from a function inside the framework. `console.log(test);` at the very end will output [[13, 39, 9]], instead of doing it for each element of the var arr. I guess this is because `this` is overwritten when foreach is called internally.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop's index (`i`) in your `foreach` method is being overwritten because you've declared it in the global scope. Always use `var` to declare variables:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {
    values[i] = callback.call(this, this.element[i], i);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QhXa7/

Comment: @user2180613 It was a pain to find :) Everything looked good, so I didn't understand why it wouldn't work. Then I randomly realized the `var` wasn't there, added it and tried again, and it worked :)

Comment: Getting into a habit of dumping your code through JShint is a good way to catch this sort of bug before it grows into an actual problem.